# Eloquent Javascript, local variables are parameters?

Tags: javascript

I was reading the book when I saw this

```
function multiplier(factor) {
  return number => number * factor;
}
```

1. I know that closures are functions within functions that access the parent function's local variables but is a returned function still considered a closure?
2. If this is considered a closure, that means that parameters are also considered local variables. Is this true? If so, is this true in every programming language? I've seen some posts saying that they're not exactly the same. What are the differences?

Comment: 1. Yes, it has a free variable named `factor`. 2. Yes, parameters are scoped by function. Not necessary that is true in every language. From the top of the head I cannot think of how they would differ in runtime (spec technically can put some differences, but not necessary any of those are observable in userland)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. While it's true that this is an example of a closure , this is also an example of a curried function.
2. Yes, the function with its  parameters and local variables are added to the call stack and that's true in (most?) programming languages.  I don't know of any language where that isn't true, but one could be written otherwise so I'm sure someone's done it.  I would say the major difference between parameters/arguments and local variables is that the function has control over the local variables whereas the parameters are controlled by whatever is calling it. You can see the difference here, but they are more or less the same.

```js
// You'll need to actually look in your dev tools to see the result

const test = test => test2 => test2;
console.log("Test:");
console.dir(test);
console.dir(test());
const best = function(best) {
    return function(best2) {
        return best2;
    }
}
console.log("Best:");
console.dir(best);
console.dir(best());

// You'll need to actually look in your dev tools to see the result
```

Comment: "example of function currying" --- currying is a process of turning a function of N arguments into N functions of 1 argument. It's not "an example of function currying", but "an example of a curried function" (the difference is crucial: a process vs a result)

Answer (score 2):

You are asking more than one question here, but the question in the title is whether parameters in javascript are local to the function where it is used. The answer is yes plus all nested functions.

Answer (score 2):

I'm worried that you are taking 'closures' too seriously. A so-called "closure" - is just a place where scope exists / or the boundary of that scope. factor becomes a local variable to that function... and so, it's in that function's scope... - and some people like to use the conceptual model that it *closes* around that... but - I've seen this mental model cause more harm than good. Functions have scope. The parameter/argument is in that function's scope. Sometimes trying to name a fact is just an unnecessary abstraction. But it if works for you, then that's great too. Just don't force it.

```
function multiplier(factor) {
  // var factor = undefined; // is how you can think of it
  // factor = incomingArgument
  console.log('factor:', factor);

  return function(number) {
    // var number = undefined;
    // number = incomingArgument
    console.log('number:', number);
    return number * factor;
    // factor is coming from that outer scope only
  }
}

var outer = multiplier;
var inner = multiplier(4);
var outcome = inner(5);

console.log('outer', outer);
console.log('inner', inner);
console.log('outcome', outcome);
```

from `{` to `}` would be the scope.

https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/z1juda8L/